# Netfilter kernel module migrating to 4.1.23 - cannot retrieve ip header

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, netfilter

We have a netfilter kernel module from 2.6 kernel and porting now to 4.1.23. My hook function looks broken. I cannot retrieve packet header.

Here is the code snippet from 2.6 kernel. This is in production for long time.

```
    static unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in,const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{
  //struct sk_buff *skb = (skb_p);
  struct iphdr *ih = (struct iphdr *)(skb->data);
  u32 saddr = ih->saddr;
  u32 daddr = ih->daddr;
```

Checked netfilter.h and searched Internet to arrive at following in 4.1.23

```
static unsigned int main_hook(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
       {
          //struct sk_buff *skb = (skb_p);
          struct iphdr *ih = (struct iphdr *)(skb->data);
          u32 saddr = ih->saddr;
          u32 daddr = ih->daddr;
```

Registered hook as follows.

```
  netfilter_ops.hook              =       main_hook;
  netfilter_ops.pf                =       PF_INET;
  netfilter_ops.hooknum           =       NF_INET_FORWARD;
  netfilter_ops.priority          =       NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
  netfilter_ops.owner             =       THIS_MODULE;
  nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops);
```

I am not getting source ip and destination ip from saddr and daddr.

Removed everything and tried following

```
static unsigned int main_hook(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
  struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *) (skb->data);
  unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;
  unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;
  printk("IP addres = %pI4  DEST = %pI4\n", &src_ip, &dest_ip);
  return NF_ACCEPT;
```

Here is the result

```
[37501.345997] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37506.337854] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37511.345295] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37516.337132] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37521.344589] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37526.336426] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
[37531.343866] IP addres = 0.0.0.0  DEST = 0.0.0.0
```

Tried following too but getting junk

```
buff = (unsigned char *) skb->data;
for (i=0;i<60;i++) printk("%d.", buff[i]);
printk("\n");
```

I tried using functions to get data (skb_network_header), even tried writing hello world.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extract this way:

```
struct iphdr *ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
```

and access this way:

```
printk("IP addres = %u  DEST = %u\n", ip_hdr->saddr, ip_hdr->daddr);
```